# CSS classes are not getting executed for one line

Tags: html, navigation, tailwind-css

Have a "contact us" button at the top of the page (in the nav bar) and a "contact form" at the end of the page. I want to navigate to the end section of the page when the "contact us" button is clicked (In-page navigation).
Code for the button:

```html
    <nav>
      <a href="#contact">
        <button
          class="inline-flex items-center bg-gray-800 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0">Contact
          Us
          <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
            class="w-4 h-4 ml-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </a>
    </nav>
```

The code for the form:

```html
<section id="contact" class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="py-8 lg:py-16 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-md">
        <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Contact Us</h2>
        <p class="mb-8 lg:mb-16 font-light text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-xl">Got a technical issue? Have a suggession? Need details about our platform? Any other doubts? Let us know.</p>
        <form action=" " class="space-y-8" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Your email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light" placeholder="xyz@gmail.com" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="subject" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" id="subject" class="block p-3 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light" placeholder="Let us know how we can help you" required>
            </div>
            <div class="sm:col-span-2">
                <label for="message" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">Your message</label>
                <textarea id="message" rows="6" class="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="py-3 px-5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white rounded-lg bg-primary-700 sm:w-fit hover:bg-primary-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Send message</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Here the first line of code for the form is not working properly: `<section id="contact" class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">`
The tailwind CSS classes are not getting executed for that line.
I tried adding `id=contact` to each of the tags in the forms one at a lime, but in each case, the same thing is happening, ie: The css for that particular tag wont work.

Eg: This is how the form looks if `id="contact"` is not there on line 1:
[Expected result even after adding in-page navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm0lo.png)

when `id="contact"` is added:
[Here the in-page navigation works but CSS doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1iYl.png)

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked your [browser devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)?  Click on the element that you're having problems with, and you will see the styles that are being applied.  It sounds like something is overriding them - you will be able to identify what and why.

Comment: Actually, if I remove the ```id="contact"``` from the sections tab it works absolutely fine. But at that time the in-page navigation won't be there. To solve this I thought of removing the id from the sections tab and then adding it to a <p> tag, and it's working but I don't know whether it's the right way (good practice) to add the id into a <p> tag as there is no need of the <p> tag. If this id is kept in any other existing tab then the CSS applied to that tab won't work. what to do?

Comment: If removing the ID solves the CSS problem, it suggests there is some CSS applied to that ID which is causing the problem.  The best practice fix would be to find that CSS clash, and address it.

Comment: How about keeping ```<p id="contact"></p>```  it solves every problem, but is it a good practice?

Comment: The code I provided demonstrates the same! In this case, the CSS does not appear for that tag! I tried with regular CSS it's working, but here it's tailwind, I think it's something related to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by providing a `<p>` tag just after the `<section>` tag.
So the final code is:

```
<section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
   <p id="contact"></p>
    <div class="py-8 lg:py-16 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-md">
        <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Contact Us</h2>
        <p class="mb-8 lg:mb-16 font-light text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-xl">Got a technical issue? Have a suggession? Need details about our platform? Any other doubts? Let us know.</p>
        <form action=" " class="space-y-8" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Your email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light" placeholder="xyz@gmail.com" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="subject" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" id="subject" class="block p-3 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light" placeholder="Let us know how we can help you" required>
            </div>
            <div class="sm:col-span-2">
                <label for="message" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">Your message</label>
                <textarea id="message" rows="6" class="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500" placeholder="Leave a comment..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="py-3 px-5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white rounded-lg bg-primary-700 sm:w-fit hover:bg-primary-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Send message</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </section>
```